# how to evenly space out drop down box?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to evenly space out my drop down box. I want the options to be evenly spaced out whenever the user select a drop down box. I tried using margin and this seems to work but for some reason, I can't get it to push down further enough....

```
<div class="subscriptionplan">
         <select name="subscriptionplan">
            <option value="">Choose Subscription Plan 1</option>
            <option value="None">None</option>
            <option value="Level 1">Level 1</option>
            <option value="Level 2">Level 2</option>
            <option value="Level 3">Level 3</option>
         </select>
         <br></br>
         <select name="pricing_level1">
          <option value="">Choose a price plan for Level 1</option>
          <option value="None">None</option>
          <option value="100">Monthly:$100</option>
          <option value="800">Yearly:$800</option>
          </select>
        <br></br>
        <select name="pricing_level2">
          <option value="">Choose a price plan for Level 2</option>
          <option value="None">None</option>
          <option value="150">Monthly:$150</option>
          <option value="1300">Yearly:$1300</option>
          </select>
          <br></br>
          <select name="pricing_level3">
          <option value="">Choose a price plan for Level 3</option>
          <option value="None">None</option>
          <option value="200">Monthly:$200</option>
          <option value="1800">Yearly:$1800</option>
          </select>

         <br></br>
         <button type="submit" name="submit">Sign up</button>
      </form>
           </div>

This is the CSS code:

div.subscriptionplan {
  position: absolute;
  right: 180em;
  bottom: 60em;
}
div.subscriptionplan select{
   margin: 180em;

}
```

Comment: Q @musician888 what you mean by "spaced out"?

Comment: `break` tags are self closing, meaning you don't need an additional tag to close it. Thus you should replace `<br></br>` with `<br />`

Comment: why don't you do them as radio buttons instead?

Comment: when the user click on the drop down box, it looks like it is overlapping the second drop down box but I realised that it looks good when zoom in and not zoom out

Comment: I am not sure if it is working though....

Comment: _“when the user click on the drop down box, it looks like it is overlapping the second drop down box”_ - that is how select fields work; they do not push following content further down when they are “opened”. If you want something that does that, then you can not use a standard select element, but will have to built something yourself.

Answer (score 0):

em is not equal to px.

```
div.subscriptionplan {
  position: absolute;
  right: 180em;
  bottom: 60em;
}
div.subscriptionplan select{
   margin: 180em;

}
```

/* ------------------------*/
You did not add the context for absolute position.
assuming that you need css for spacing select boxes side by side please refer below. you can remove br tags.

```
div.subscriptionplan {
    /*  position: absolute;
      right: 180em;
      bottom: 60em;*/
      display:block;
      width:100%;
    }
    div.subscriptionplan select{
      /* margin: 180em;*/
       margin:0.5em;
       display:inline-block;
       max-width:33.3%;

    }
```

Comment: thanks but what do you mean by not adding the context for absolute position?

Comment: .subscriptionplan is positioned absolute and I do not know why it has to be in absolute positioned. if it has any significance or how inner elements will get effected.

Comment: oh.... I have used position absolute for almost everything... I thought that by using position absolute, it won't affect other images? Am I using it incorrectly?

Comment: No, actually by positioning elements in absolute state you are removing them from their natural order.

Comment: oh... I have been wondering why some of my pictures can't be moved at all

Comment: how would I know when to use position absolute or relevant? or I know is that for a parent class, i should use position relevant

Comment: There are no hard and fast rules for when to use and when not to. its solely depends upon requirement. and you will learn them while putting it at practice and experimenting. look into other pages and inspect in the browser you will learn a lot. or else you will get all the information and learn better from this place. https://developer.mozilla.org/kab/docs/Web/CSS

Comment: thanks and I tried the above but when zoom out, it still looks overlapped as the user clicks on the drop down box but looks okay when zoom in

Comment: if I have many menus inside my drop down box, will this always overlapped the other drop down box?

Comment: Yes that's how select option tag works, and its same in every browser, UI might change slightly. the moment you select one option it closes automatically. so no issue I presume.